QMA-QCMA oracle with quantum gates
While reading the QMA-QCMA paper by Aaronson and Kuperberg I wondered how their result extends to quantum circuits.
Suppose you have an oracle $O$ such that $O\left|\psi\right>=-\left|\psi\right>$ and $O\left|\phi\right>=\left|\phi\right>$, whenever $\left<\phi|\psi\right> = 0$.
Distinguishing between the oracle $O$ and an identity oracle $I$ requires $\Omega(2^{n/2})$ queries in general.
I wonder how this result extends to situations where you are allowed to perform computations between successive oracle calls.
It seems that Aaronson and Kuperberg do not explicitly rule out intermediate operations, yet I cannot seem to formalize this statement.
Consider the sequence of gates $K_t = U_n \dots U_t O U_{t-1} O\dots U_1 O$, where the first $t$ times, an oracle is applied between a quantum circuit $U_i$ and afterwards, only identity gates are applied in between.
In this setting, what can we say about $K_{n}\left|0\right>$ with respect to $K_0\left|0\right>$?
And similarly, what can we say about $|\left<\psi\right|(K_{n}-K_0)\left|0\right>|$?

Couldn't you just absorb $K_t = U_n \dots U_t O U_{t-1} O\dots U_1 O$ and call it a new oracle, $\tilde O$? Maybe I'm missing something?
